# How to extract particular line from text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file having following content:

```
9.0 4.000000000001712e-05
8.996 0.009553763042602704
8.976 0.005684452508893222
8.96 -0.00353920143256147
8.956 -0.0044586273593916585
8.936 -0.012284767416576208
8.916 -0.019094598621809324
8.9 -0.020204776832571356
```

I have to extract each line starting with single point decimal number and write these numbers in a new file. 
like:

```
9.0 4.000000000001712e-05
8.9 -0.020204776832571356
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex will work:

```
^\d*(?:\.\d{1,1})?\s
```

Comment: Already tried regex but it writing whole content of file f1 to file f2

Comment: If I am using r"^\d*\.\d{1,1}\s regex pattern, then also it is working. I didn't understand ?:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        vals = line.split(' ')
        if len(vals[0].split('.')[1]) == 1:
            print(line)
```

Comment: could you explain this code   if len(vals[0].split('.')[1]) == 1: